# помогите настроить счетчик

Tags: java, счетчики

В предлагаемом коде из Эккеля захотел посчитать порядковый номер генерирования числа, до момента, когда будет удовлетворять условию.
Общее число обращений выдает, а мне нужно, чтобы после каждого обращения счетчик увеличивался на 1.

```
    package study.it.java.Eccel000077;

public class Eccel000077p130loopWhile {
    static boolean condition() {
        double rndm = Math.random();
        System.out.println(rndm);
        boolean result = rndm < 0.99;
        System.out.println(result + ", ");
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (condition())
            counter++;
        System.out.println(counter);
        System.out.println("Inside 'while'");

        System.out.println("Exited 'while");
    }
}
```

В консоли вот что:

```
[...]
0.4126061797246662
true,
0.9893111158958946
true,
0.10166477691349951
true,
0.9965451426395308
false,
13
Inside 'while'
Exited 'while
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно скобками обернуть тело цикла:

```
 while (condition()) {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(counter);
    System.out.println("Inside 'while'");
 }
```